# php/html - if a new tab already exists, don't create a new one

Tags: javascript, html

So I am using php to list out some users from the database and have put a <a href="" link with them.. The issue is, I want to be able to open the new file on a new tab but if i use `target="_blank`" everytime i click on that link a new tab will open. I don't want that. Once a new tab has been created, if i click on it again, it should take me to the tab thats already open.
Yes, I have looked this up on stackoverflow and i did come across this solution:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

var myWindow = null;
$('.title').on('click', function(){
  if(myWindow == null || myWindow.closed)
    myWindow = window.open('i.php', 'myWindow')
  else
    myWindow.focus()
});

</script>
```

So I understand how to use this for an html page or when you have to directly go to a page but I am making use of php and `?id=`to go to a different page.. Not just that, my a link in php has been set inside a while loop so that all users could be displayed from the list.

```
while($msg=mysqli_fetch_assoc($msgs))
        {
            $s=mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `Email`='".$msg['Email']."'");
            while($ms=mysqli_fetch_assoc($s))
                {
                echo '<div class="w3-col m3"><a href="chatbox.php?toUser='.$msg['Email'].'" target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer">
              <img src="black.png"></a><br>
             <label for="name">'.$ms['FullName'].'</label><br>';
    }
}
```

so as you can see.. here I need to find a way to click on the <a link and for a new tab to open just once and then if i click on the same thing again, it should just take me back to the same tab.. But I am not able to figure out how to do this

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using [parameterized queries](https://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [`bind_param`](https://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add any data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you have created a severe [SQL injection bug](https://bobby-tables.com/). **NEVER** put `$_POST`, `$_GET` or data *of any kind* directly into a query, it can be very harmful if someone seeks to exploit your mistake.

Answer (score 0):

If you specify `target="_blank"` then it will open up in a new tab. If you specify `target="..."` with a unique name, then it will try and reference a window with that name.

You need to construct some kind of unique name per tab.

If you're using `window.open()` you've got to keep track of any previously opened windows, so I'd suggest some kind of object where the key is the tab and the value is the window created.

> It's worth noting that `window.open()` is really user hostile, it's considered a "pop up" by some blockers, and you should let `target` do the work for you.

Comment: I am still kinda confused as to how I can accomplish what i want.. My biggest issue is that each page will be different .. for example chatbox.php?userid=1, chatbox.php?userid=2, chatbox.php?userid=3 etc. I dont know how i can define that.

Comment: Having that many tabs is a whole lot for a user to try and keep track of. Are you sure you want to do this versus having on-page tabs or letting the user decide which they want to "Open in new tab"?

Comment: based on the work I am doing.. The user will probably find it a lot easier if I do it that way.

Comment: Up to you, but you do need to keep track of which tabs are already open. Note the `windowName` argument on [`window.open()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/open) which is described as "if the name doesn't indicate an existing context, a new window is created". You need a way of generating a unique name per "window".